# How to remove Docker distros from WSL?

Tags: windows-10, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I've installed Docker Desktop and Ubuntu 20.04 [Microsoft Store] on Windows 10 and see that I have three distros [below], but I want to get rid of `docker-desktop` and `docker-desktop-data`, as I don't need so many of them and want to use `Ubuntu-20.04` for my Docker experiments only:

```
PS $ wsl -l -v

  NAME                    STATE           VERSION
  Ubuntu-20.04            Running         2
  docker-desktop-data     Running         2
  docker-desktop          Running         2
```

- I know `docker-desktop-data` contains images and `docker-desktop` contains the Docker infrastructure, but it's still unclear to me and confusing

How do I delete these and do I need them?

Comment: It appears based on the downvote, I might need some additional information, to confirm you have actually installed Docker within your Ubuntu WSL2 instance.  Those instances you want to remove are required for Docker Desktop.  If you were to remove them, I suspect you would immediately, lose all your Docker containers.  Can you confirm you have specifically and explicitly installed Docker with Ubuntu?  If you haven’t explicitly installed it, don’t be shocked that something like, *docker ps -a* still works (that’s not a valid way to confirm Docker was literally installed on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I mentioned this yesterday in a comment on Stack Overflow, but I've now had a chance to try it out, and it works as expected ...

Docker Engine will run just fine in a single WSL2 instance (with one known caveat, see below for workaround), and it sounds like that's what you really want.

Docker Desktop does provide a few additional features over the base Docker Engine:

- It can be shared amongst multiple WSL2 instances
- It can run from PowerShell and CMD
- It provides a GUI dashboard of containers and volumes
- It handles automatic upgrades (although some might not consider that necessarily an advantage)
- It's a convenience method that handles all of the other stuff below automatically for you.

If you don't need those features, then:

- Backup any volumes and images from your existing Docker Desktop installation
- Uninstall Docker Desktop (the two referenced `docker-desktop.*` instances will be removed)
- Optional, but recommended:  Reboot Windows, or at least `wsl --shutdown`
- Install Docker Engine in the Ubuntu instance per the [normal instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).  For the purposes of this answer, use the "Install from a package" and just do steps 1 and 2 for now.  The `docker run` example won't work yet.
- The normal Docker package installation will attempt to start the daemon, but that doesn't work on WSL since there's no concept of runlevels, startup scripts, systemd, etc.  You'll need to manually start it via `sudo service docker start`.
- Now you can run the example `sudo docker run --rm hello-world` (why the Docker doc doesn't have `--rm` in it makes no sense to me).  And clean it up with `sudo docker rmi hello-world` (also should be part of the doc, IMHO).
- Continue to the Post-Installation steps to allow your normal user to be able to run Docker without `sudo`.

After that, the next step in the Docker doc is to enable it to run on boot.  This won't work on WSL, since there's no concept of a "boot".  So you'll need an alternate method to make sure the engine is running in WSL.  That can, of course, simply be a manual `sudo service docker start` when you need it.  Or you can, if you'd like, add something like the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start"
```

There are other methods as well, but that's just one example.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I delete these? Do I need them?

If you deleted them you would break your Docker configuration.

> Now I want to get rid of these 2. I don't need so many of them.

You actually need both of them.  The reason they exist has been explained by Docker themselves:

> The new WSL backend design is very close to that, with the difference that we don’t run the LinuxKit distro in a VM but… in a container.
>
> [image]
>
> This will create 2 WSL distros for you:
>
> - Docker-desktop, which I’ll call the bootstrapping distro
> - Docker-desktop-data, which I’ll call the data store distro
>
> From a high level perspective, the bootstrapping distro essentially replaces Hyper-V, while the data store distro replaces the VHD that we previously attached to the VM.

Source: [Introducing the Docker Desktop WSL 2 Backend](https://www.docker.com/blog/new-docker-desktop-wsl2-backend/)

Comment: Now if you are saying you installed Docker within your Ubuntu WSL2 installation, then you no longer need Docker Desktop, and could simply uninstall it.  However, every single article I read about running Docker within Ubuntu WSL2 refers to Docker Desktop.  So I suspect it’s required to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

- 

> How do I delete these and do I need them?

- 

You should not delete it if you like the integration benefits Docker Desktop really enables different distro to talk to each other.

---

**docker-desktop-data ,docker-desktop**  disto are part of the Docker Desktop architecture.

These three articles sums up well.

1. https://www.nextofwindows.com/running-docker-inside-ubuntu-with-wsl2-windows-10
2. https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/03/02/docker-in-wsl2
3. https://www.docker.com/blog/new-docker-desktop-wsl2-backend/