# Docker on WSL erroring: "docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a project for a paid internship at my school that requires that I install docker on a WSL ubuntu instance. However, after I follow the instructions from [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to install docker and then running

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

I get the error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I found some other questions from people who had the same problem, and they recommended either running `systemctl start docker`, which doesn't work due to the fact that `systemd` isn't the init system in WSL, or running `dockerd` (the docker daemon). I tried this, errored:

```
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.183317500-04:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.219667900-04:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=10598
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.219758500-04:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.219782400-04:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.219819200-04:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.219854500-04:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.254159100-04:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3 version=1.4.9
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.271842300-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.271938000-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282592100-04:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282655000-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282826400-04:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (wslfs) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282846500-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282873900-04:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.282891500-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283006900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283468100-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283622300-04:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283650700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283687900-04:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.283719100-04:00" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284129000-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284158200-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284196800-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284238500-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284256900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284311100-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284336000-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284383600-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284411900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284430700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284448100-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284738900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.284970100-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups\"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285348400-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285376700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.restart\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285462400-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285492300-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285526300-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285547200-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.events\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285567300-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285587700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.images\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285608600-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285627700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285647900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.opt\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285727800-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285757700-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285778300-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.version\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.285796900-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.288091300-04:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.290093400-04:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.290649900-04:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.290688200-04:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.048662s"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.304911700-04:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.304940700-04:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.304998900-04:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.305013000-04:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.305870600-04:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.305910200-04:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.305928800-04:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.305957000-04:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.313617500-04:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316205300-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316237300-04:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316245800-04:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316253900-04:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316261600-04:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find pids cgroup in mounts"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.316390300-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.325245700-04:00" level=warning msg="Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)\nPerhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`, error: exit status 3"
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.501619100-04:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.502669400-04:00" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
time="2021-08-13T14:42:48.502675100-04:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
time="2021-08-13T14:42:49.504913000-04:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

I tried upgrading iptables and my kernel (by running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) and there was no change. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does the WSL2 instance have an IP address? You are running a WSL2 instance right?

Comment: @Ramhound No, I'm running WSL 1.

Comment: If you want to use Docker on Windows you should probably be using Docker Desktop. It does all setup for you.

Comment: @hexagonNoah - That’s why it isn’t working. Instructions you were using are not applicable to WSL1 (nor WSL2) only supported verse of Ubuntu. There are different instructions for Docker within WSL2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have followed instructions to install Docker on Ubuntu, which is a real
Linux distribution. This does not suite WSL, because Docker has to be
installed *in Windows*.

The Microsoft description is found in the article
[Get started with Docker remote containers on WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers).

The article lists the prerequisites:

- Windows 10 at least version 2004
- Enabled WSL, install a Linux distribution, and update to WSL 2
- The Linux kernel update package.

Once this is done:

- Install Docker Desktop *in Windows*
- Enable WSL integration with the Docker engine that is installed in Windows.

The details are found in the article, the above is only a short summary
of the steps.

The Docker documentation for installation on Windows is found in
[Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)
and might be useful to complete the Microsoft article.

Comment: Just a heads-up that Docker Engine *can* be installed directly into a WSL instance.  See [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1662581/1210833) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a copy/paste from a similar issue I answered recently on Stack Overflow:

You are installing Docker Engine directly on Ubuntu WSL, which is fine, but I want to be sure you understand that you have another option.  The "recommended" method (as @harrymc pointed out) is to install [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows).

Docker Desktop does provide a few additional features over the base Docker Engine:

- It can be shared amongst multiple WSL2 instances
- It can run from PowerShell and CMD
- It provides a GUI dashboard of containers and volumes
- It handles automatic upgrades (although some might not consider that necessarily an advantage)
- It's a convenience method that handles all of the other stuff below automatically for you.

Both versions run the same engine underneath, but Desktop just provides those additional convenience features as well.  If you don't need or want these, and you really *do* want to just install Docker Engine, then the solution to your current issue should be to just run:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Then try the sample again.  It's an extra step that's required in WSL that isn't covered in the Docker doc.

(Bonus tip) I recommend running `hello-world` via:

```
sudo docker run --rm hello-world
```

There's no reason to leave that particular container hanging around after it exits, IMHO.  I wish Docker would update those docs.

Also, assuming everything works at that point, I recommend getting rid of that image via:

```
sudo docker rmi hello-world
```

*Explanation:*

On "regular" Ubuntu, part of the installation process performed by the `docker-ce` package is to start the Docker daemon.  However, that step fails due to differences in the way WSL works (lack of runlevels, systemd, startup script support, etc).

So when you get to that (currently) Step 3 to verify that the daemon is running via `docker run ...`, it's not.

You're also going to run into a similar issue when you get to the section "Post-installation steps for Linux:  Configure Docker to start on boot"*

This won't work on WSL, since there's no concept of a "boot" (and, again, no Systemd).  So you'll need an alternate method to make sure the engine is running in WSL.  That can, of course, simply be a manual `sudo service docker start` when you need it.  Or you can, if you'd like, add something like the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
wsl.exe -u root -e sh -c "service docker status || service docker start"
```

There are other methods as well, but that's just one example.